# Wordpress upload size reduced to under 20MB even though it says the limit is 505MB - happened within last 24hrs

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a file sharing form on our website, which allows file uploads of up to 505MB. To enable this, I did the following:

In Plesk, changed the PHP settings for the site subscription to the following:

- memory_limit = 530M
- max_execution_time = 300
- max_input_time = 250
- post_max_size = 525M
- upload_max_filesize = 505M

In the Apache / NGINX settings, in the additional directives for BOTH http and https:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 100
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
</IfModule>
```

In a .conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d (which gets loaded into the http block in nginx.conf):

```
client_max_body_size 512M;
```

Previously these settings worked fine for our customers, but today suddenly they don't.  On the front end of the site, when the customer submits the file upload they get an error message "Request Entity Too Large" which usually means the nginx client body max size is not big enough.

I thought it was the form, but when I checked the Wordpress media library from the admin and it also cannot upload a bigger file - even though it shows 505M on the wordpress upload window "Maximum upload file size: 505 MB." It just says "http error"

What I've Tried:

- Double checking all of the above to make sure it hadn't changed.
- loaded a phpinfo file and confirmed the correct config and directives are used
- Restarting the server
- Searching the forums, but no solutions have worked, such as:
- adding rules to .htaccess
- adding rules to php.ini in /wp-admin folder
- adding rules to wp-config.php
- deactivating all plugins
- reverting to a default theme

Has this happened to anyone else? I'm wondering if it was a plesk update or php update that caused it, or if it's related to just my server. It is happening to other sites on our shared server too, not just one. I hope I've explained it enough -  appreciate the help.

Comment: Is your server behind a load balancer, firewall, etc.? Or a service like Cloudflare?

Comment: Disk space full?

Comment: JohnEllmore, there is a firewall I believe, but its settings have not changed in months. No Cloudflare or related service.  Tyr, Nope! I'm using about 70% of the disk space right now. Memory and CPU are also in normal levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found!

In the end, I went to plesk.com and paid for a support service (only $10/mo) and their developers figured it out in about 6 hours and 8 emails. Turns out, it was an issue with a plesk microupdate that enabled ModSecurity, which applies its own limits on upload size in a config file that loads a module.

****In their words:

One of Modsecurity packages contains the configuration file /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-mod_security.conf which loads security2_module by default

However, Plesk treats modsecurity as disabled by default. Therefore we have such discrepancy: Plesk shows modsecurity as disabled but it is actually enabled on the server. Also, it is not possible to disable modsecurity with the command:

```
# plesk sbin modsecurity_ctl -d
```

This behavior has been submitted as a bug PPPM-8557 which is planned to be fixed in one of the future Plesk updates.

So, in order to stop ModSecurity from messing with things, it was temporarily disabled by enabling and disabling it in Plesk UI.

I can confirm that the upload form is now working as it should. Plesk.com paid support WELL worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

**Plesk Control Panel:**

1. Firstly, log into your Plesk Control Panel.
2. Select 'Domains' from the left hand Navigation Panel.
3. Select desired domain's 'Manage In Customer Panel' link.
4. You should see a Panel like the following:

[image]

5. Simply select the 'PHP Settings' link.
6. Scroll down to the 'Performance Settings' area and modify the 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size'.
7. There may be a maximum limit, from your drop down menu.  Simply ignore the drop down options and manually enter the correct numbers.  For example: 505M.
8. What you are doing here, is setting a maximum allowed file size within the Plesk Control Panel.  If your `php.ini` exceeds this amount, it will 'default' back to the maximum allowed set within the Plesk Control Panel.

**`php.ini` File:**

Next, you will need to head to:

```
/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini
```

Then made the relevant modifications within the `php.ini` file.  Needless to say, `example.com` being the affected domain.

Setting the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` accordingly, ensuring they are within the limits set within your Plesk Control Panel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig. Unfortunately that php.ini is automatically generated by Plesk, and set in the plesk subscription settings. I did double check it though, and it is already showing the correct directives. That's what's so odd, even Wordpress media library is showing 505MB upload limit, but in practice it's not allowing uploads anywhere near that size.

Comment: No worries.  Just to check, you are accessing your web files via Root Access?

Comment: It depends, I use root access to view/edit root files like in the /etc folder. If it's dynamically generated by plesk, I don't directly edit it at all but view it via root.  If it's related to a specific subscription and accessible within the /httpdocs folder, I use the subscription SFTP login. For checking all the PHP directives, I'm typically using a phpinfo() file temporarily added to the subscription.

Comment: Additional things I've tried this morning: Plesk repair all, no change. Editing the PHP default php.ini for php 7.1.17 in plesk PHP settings screen. If I change the defaults to 64M in the subscription then restart httpd and nginx, I can visually see the change in Wordpress media library but it still errors out with the "HTTP error". So no matter what changes I make to any php.ini, the settings are not being honored by Wordpress for any site on the server.

Comment: Update. I did some testing to try and find out a closer idea of the limits the server is putting on the sites.  I can upload a 10.6MB file, but not a 11.1MB File. This suggests the limit is 11MB, which is a really weird and random amount considering the default for Wordpress is 8MB, and the default in my php.ini is 64MB, and my custom setting for the subscription is 505MB. Something else is controlling the size limitations!

Comment: That is strange.  Generally, I limit Media Uploads to 2MB.  When I do need to temporarily increase the file limit, I have no problems with my suggestion above.  Do you use Plesk?

Comment: Yup, Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 Update #51, last updated on May 15, 2018 01:30 AM.  Which is why I'm thinking the plesk update broke something.

Comment: I have just modified my answer.  Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Those steps had been completed already during my early troubleshooting. I have confirmed through Plesk and a phpinfo() file that the directives are set, just for some reason Wordpress is ignoring them. I do appreciate you taking the time to update your suggestion though. The php.ini file you reference at "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini" is set dynamically via Plesk, so directly editing it would have no permanent affect.

Comment: Did you say you have a php.ini file within the wp-admin folder?

Comment: Yup, that's one of the methods I tried during early troubleshooting, didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean install of WordPress followed by using their 2017 default theme (https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/). Obviously, do a back up of your Web Files and MySql Database first. If the problem goes away, then atleast we can say the issue resides within your current WordPress core files/theme.

Comment: I could certainly try that, but this problem is not localized to one site. It's affecting all sites on my VPS, that use different themes and plugins. Knowing that, I have to assume it's a server issue and not a site issue - but at this point I might be desperate enough to try it just to check that box.

Comment: Running out of ideas, unfortunately.  It does sound server related, if all sites are affected.  That is, unless there is a conflicting file, which appears on all sites.  As a 'stab in the dark', do you have the same `.htaccess` and `config.php` files across all sites?  After making a back up of each, maybe try removing any modified `.htaccess` and `config.php` files; replacing them with the default versions.  Also, check the themes' `functions.php` file.  Are there any line breaks between any closing `?>` and opening `<?php` tags.  I once had a line break, which affected the Media Uploader.